# dlsym import method once for subsequent use

Tags: c

Please consider the below code

`shared.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void printCharArray(char *someArray){
    if (!someArray){
        printf("someArray is null!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Array is %s\n", someArray);
    }
}
```

and `question.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define LIB "/tmp/some.so"

void *handle = 0;

void localfunc();

int main(){
    handle = dlopen(LIB, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle){
        fprintf(stderr, "dlopen err\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    dlerror();
    void (*printCharArray)() = dlsym(handle, "printCharArray");
    char *err = dlerror();
    if (err){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    printCharArray(); // some work
    localfunc();
}


void localfunc(){
    puts("localfunc");
    dlerror();
    void (*printCharArray)() = dlsym(handle, "printCharArray"); // <- This 
    char *err = dlerror();
    if (err){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }
    printCharArray(); // do some work in localfunc
}
```

Compile and run

```sh
 2035  gcc -shared -o /tmp/some.so shared.c -fPIC
 2036  gcc -ldl question.c


$ ./a.out 
someArray is null!
localfunc
someArray is null!
```

Notice how in `localfunc` I call `dlsym` again to import `"printCharArray"` which was previously done in `main()`. I am looking to avoid this - how can I make this method available after the 1st import? (iow, how can I make my 1st import to be available as a fn prototype for use anywhere in `question.c`?)

Comment: Make the function pointer global?  Also, you're not declaring it with the parameter so it's incompatible with the definition.

Comment: @dbush, could you please show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: Or pass the function pointer as an argument to `localfunc`

Comment: `void (*printCharArray)(char *)`

Comment: And then call it with an argument.

Comment: Note that `dlerror()` does not print anything.  It returns a pointer to a string which you should copy or print.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just realized the reason for the bare calls to `dlerror()`. It resets the error state. But it's not necessary since the next `dlXXX()` call will set the error state appropriately, there's no need to clear in between.

Comment: ty, just to clarify my take, blank invocation of `dlerror()` is to clear out any prior errors. man page:  `returns  a human-readable, null-terminated string describing the most recent error that occurred from a call to one of the  functions in the dlopen API since the last call to dlerror().`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the function pointer as a global variable, rather than local to `main()`.

Give it the correct parameter declaration so the call matches the definition. And then call it with an argument.

There's no point in calling `dlerror()` before calling `dlsym()`. And it doesn't do anything useful if you don't assign the result to something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define LIB "/tmp/some.so"

void *handle = 0;

void localfunc();
void (*printCharArray)(char *);

int main(){
    handle = dlopen(LIB, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle){
        fprintf(stderr, "dlopen err: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
    printCharArray = dlsym(handle, "printCharArray");
    if (!printCharArray) {
        char *err = dlerror();
        printf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    printCharArray(NULL); // some work
    localfunc();
}


void localfunc(){
    puts("localfunc");
    printCharArray("something"); // do some work in localfunc
}
```